# How can I disable dates in Element UI datepicker?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I want to  select the departure date then when I go to select the return date I want the function to disable all dates before the departure date in element UI

I was able to disable all date before today's date Here is the function

```
disabledDate(time) {
      var date = new Date();
      var previousDate = date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
        return time.getTime() < previousDate;  
    },
```

Comment: What module are you using for date picker?

Comment: @Naren he is using https://element.eleme.io/

Comment: element.eleme.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the picker-options to disable the date:

```
var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        value2: '',
        fromDate: null,
        pickerOptions: {
          disabledDate: this.disabledDate,
          onPick: this.pick
        }
      };
    },
  methods: {
    pick({ maxDate, minDate }) {
      this.fromDate = minDate;
    },
    disabledDate(date) {
       if (this.fromDate) {
         return this.fromDate > date
       }
       return false;
     }
  }
};
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

> Make sure the `pick` and disabledDate options are in the method section and not inline else you couldn't access the data fields with `this`

Also don't forget the cleanup the fromDate, else somebody want to set a different range. He maybe want to have a different start date.

https://codepen.io/reijnemans/pen/vYKpRrM?editable=true%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Felement.eleme.io%2F

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implement it:

```js
methods: {
  disabledEndDate(date, departureDate) {
    // If departureDate then return valid dates after departureDate
    if (departureDate) {
      return date.getTime() < departureDate
    } else {
      // If !departureDate then return valid dates after today
      return date.getTime() < Date.now()
    }
  }
}
```

Template:

```js
<el-date-picker
  v-model="departureDate"
  type="date"
  placeholder="Pick a day."
/>
<el-date-picker
  v-model="returnDate"
  type="date"
  placeholder="Pick a day."
  :picker-options="{ disabledDate: (time) => disabledEndDate(time, departureDate) }"
/>
```

The first parameter `time` comes from the dates on the calendar.